# How to databind imageview with drawable in viewmodel?

Tags: android, kotlin, mvvm, android-databinding, android-viewmodel

***Binding Adapter:***

```
@BindingAdapter("src")
fun loadImage(imageView: ImageView, src: Any) {

    if (src is Int || src is String || src is Drawable) {
        Glide.with(imageView.context).load(src).into(imageView)
    }
}
```

***Imageview in xml:***

```
<androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatImageView
    android:layout_width="200dp"
    android:layout_height="300dp"
    app:src="@{model.image}" />
```

***View model:***

```
val image = MutableLiveData<Drawable>()

init {
    // image.value = How to initialize this?
}
```

**Scenario:**
I want to bind imageview with drawable received from server. I want to set a placeholder drawable till the image is obtained from server.

Error for the above code:

> java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Parameter specified as non-null is null: method kotlin.jvm.internal.Intrinsics.checkParameterIsNotNull, parameter src

***Note:***
1. Please provide a solution which follows MVVM. (No context in viewmodel)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Extending @Reaz Murshed's idea and after refering [Android Binding Adapter Docs](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/data-binding/binding-adapters), I created a binding adapter for all imageview's. (All imageview's need not have the same placeholder)

***Binding Adapter:***

```
@BindingAdapter(value = ["src", "placeholderImage"], requireAll = false)
fun loadImage(imageView: ImageView, src: Int?, placeholderImage: Drawable?) {
    if (placeholderImage != null) {
        Glide.with(imageView.context).load(src).placeholder(placeholderImage).into(imageView)
    } else {
        Glide.with(imageView.context).load(src).into(imageView)
    }
}

@BindingAdapter(value = ["src", "placeholderImage"], requireAll = false)
fun loadImage(imageView: ImageView, src: String?, placeholderImage: Drawable?) {
    if (placeholderImage != null) {
        Glide.with(imageView.context).load(src).placeholder(placeholderImage).into(imageView)
    } else {
        Glide.with(imageView.context).load(src).into(imageView)
    }
}

@BindingAdapter(value = ["src", "placeholderImage"], requireAll = false)
fun loadImage(imageView: ImageView, src: Drawable?, placeholderImage: Drawable?) {
    if (placeholderImage != null) {
        Glide.with(imageView.context).load(src).placeholder(placeholderImage).into(imageView)
    } else {
        Glide.with(imageView.context).load(src).into(imageView)
    }
}
```

***XML:***

```
<androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatImageView
    android:layout_width="200dp"
    android:layout_height="300dp"
    app:placeholderImage="@{@drawable/kids_ethnic_1}"
    app:src="@{model.image}" />
```

If needed we can add other methods to make placeholder of `Int` or other datatype as required.

Comment: Good to know that you could solve the problem. Kudos!

Answer (score 1):

You can set the placeholder in Glide, instead of handling that in your `ViewModel`. Just the following line should serve your purpose.

```
Glide.with(imageView.context).load(src).placeholder(R.drawable.placeholder).into(imageView)
```

See the [documentation here](https://bumptech.github.io/glide/doc/placeholders.html).